# Movie with an airplane crash, supernatural element

Tags: story-identification, movie

An NTSB investigator looking at a plane crash.  My memory of some of this is hazy. 
 This movie had very odd elements, like him dreaming about being in a plane and seeing cracks developing in the body of the plane.  Also, finding an extra arm. Turns out that he's on the plane that crashes.

I don't have any memory of time travel being involved. And, in this one, I think that, at the very end, the NTSB guy is sitting in the airplane, seeing the cracks form and realizing that the extra arm was his and that he's on the plane that's crashing. I've gone through IMDB looking for airplane crash movies and I'm starting to wonder if this was an episode on some tv series like The Outer Limits.

Answer (score 8):

Your very last instinct was the right one. ;) This *was* an episode of a mystery show. It's a segment from the first episode of *Night Visions* from 2001 called [**'The Passenger List'**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0239714/) with Aidan Quinn as the investigator.

> Aviation investigator Jeremy Bell investigates the crash of a plane he himself saw go down. He comes to believe that his daughter may have been on board and becomes desperate to find the truth. It's not too long before it becomes apparent that his daughter has been dead for quite some time before the crash. Could the **cracks** in the objects all around him be symbolic of cracks in his sanity... Or his reality?

**He also finds a severed arm** which doesn't seem to belong to any of the victims. Turns out that yup, *he's* on that plane and the cracks he keeps seeing are forming on the plane itself, which then proceeds to crash, killing him. The full episode is currently available on Youtube. Here's an image (from ShareTV):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It might be the 1989 film [*Millennium*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_(film)) (based on the John Varley short story “Air Raid”). The main character *is* an NTSB investigator who is looking into an air accident, and some strange things are happening.

Comment: @user14111 Since the original poster’s memory is “hazy”, I’m not assuming that all the details in the question are necessarily correct.

Comment: @user14111 “Very odd elements” would fit. And finding an extra arm would be in keeping with the premise of the film and provide a clue about what’s going on, though I don’t know if there is actually such a scene.

Comment: There's also a novel(ization?) of _Millennium_.

Comment: Thanks.  This sounds like a great film but I don't think it's the one I'm remembering.  I don't have any memory of time travel being involved.  And, in this one, I think that, at the very end, the NTSB guy is sitting in the airplane, seeing the cracks form and realizing that the extra arm was his and that he's on the plane that's crashing.  I've gone through IMDB looking for airplane crash movies and I'm starting to wonder if this was an episode on some tv series like The Outer Limits.